Questions on Vishistadvaita
Shri Ramanuja defines the 'sharira' as follows:


yasya cEtanasya yaddravyaM sarvAtmaNA svArthE
niyantuM dhArayituM ca shakyaM taccheShataika svarUpaM ca tat tasya sharIraM” – “Any substance
which a sentient self can completely control and support for its’ own purposes and which is entirely dependent on the self is called its sharIra


This is taken from the pdf from this website.
When Shri Ramanuja mentions that the Jiva Atmas make up the sharira of Ishwara, does he mean that the Jiva Atmas are physically attached to God and are literally a part of Him, i.e. is Ishwara a person whose intrinsic attributes are persons?
Or is the 'sharira' of Ishwara not a part of Ishwara but a thing that is completely not attached to Him in any way? In other words, are the Jiva Atmas the intrinsic features of the sharira but not the intrinsic features of the shariri? The image I have in my mind is the following: each Jiva Atma is like a plastic bubble in a large sheet of bubble wrap wrapped in a huge cylinder (see Amazon.com picture) around Ishwara (just like the physical body encompasses the individual soul/Jiva Atma) and Ishwara is the Supreme Being controlling the bubble wrap. If this is true, then Shri Ramanuja's philosophy isn't really a form of monism since there is fundamental bheda between Ishwara and the sharira of Iswhara and thus calling it '**Advaita' is incorrect.
Also, I get the idea that Shri Ramanuja is using the sharira-shariri metaphorically to illustrate the relationship between Ishwara and everything else. Is this correct?

I humbly, from whatever I know, think Ishwara in this analogy is not the thing that is in the center of bubble wrap, Ishwara is the whole of bubble wrap and there is no center.

Ishwara's body can be classified as Chit and Achit. Achit is the matter. Now Chit is conscious part forming the souls of Jeevatmas. This entire collection is called as Ishwara. If you are Ishwara, then cells in your body is Jeevatmas. But Ishwara has complete control and mastery over his body.

@HariKumar Thanks. So Shri Ramanuja's philosophy is a type of monism?

yes it is monism (more technically non dualism). But all he is saying is there is one entity but there are parts to it. Like there is one tree, but there are branches and leaves to it. So why it is referred as Qualified non dualism.

@HariKumar Thank you very much for the clarification.!!!
